# How to limit filter results by category?

Tags: jquery

As illustrated below I have a checkbox filter that filters projects based on categories. This functions how I want except that I'm trying to figure out a way to limit the filter results to show projects that match only the categories that are checked

For example if 'A' and 'B' are checked show only projects with those categories and exclude any that don't match exactly. Currently it shows every category that is checked

```js
// CHECKBOX FILTER
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var filterFunc = function() {
  
  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.box');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .animal element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current input tag data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current input tag element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.box').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
}

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);



let label = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
let cboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input");
cboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener("change", grayout.bind(null,check)))

function grayout(box) {

   if(!Array.from(cboxes).some(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) return cboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000");
   cboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      if(checkbox.checked) return checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000";
      checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#808080";
   });
}


  $('.uncheck').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
    $('.project-tag').show();
    
    cboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000";
   });
  });
```

```css
input {
  display:inline-block;
}
label {
  display:block;
}
section {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.box {
  background:#000;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="a" id="a"/>A</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="b" id=""/>B</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="c" id=""/>C</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="d" id=""/>D</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="e" id=""/>E</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="f" id=""/>F</label>
</div>
<button type="button" class="uncheck btn">Clear All</button>
<br><br>
<section>
  <div class="box" data-category="a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="c b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="d"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="e"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="f a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="c d"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should do a few things:

1. Change your `selectedFilters` into a `Set`

```
var selectedFilters = new Set();
```

2. Then populate the set

```
  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    selectedFilters.add(this.value)
  });
```

3. Then use `Array.prototype.every` to calculate your matched condition

```
var matched = [...selectedFilters].every(i => currentFilterValues.includes(i))
```

```js
// CHECKBOX FILTER
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

var filterFunc = function() {
var selectedFilters = new Set();

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    selectedFilters.add(this.value)
  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.box').filter(function() {
    var currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');
    var matched = [...selectedFilters].every(i => currentFilterValues.includes(i))
    // if matched is true the current input tag element is returned
    return matched;
  });

  $('.box').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
}

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', filterFunc);



let label = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
let cboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input");
cboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener("change", grayout.bind(null, check)))

function grayout(box) {

  if (!Array.from(cboxes).some(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) return cboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000");
  cboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    if (checkbox.checked) return checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000";
    checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#808080";
  });
}


$('.uncheck').click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false);
  $('.project-tag').show();

  cboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "#000";
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="a" id="a"/>A</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="b" id=""/>B</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="c" id=""/>C</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="d" id=""/>D</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="e" id=""/>E</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="f" id=""/>F</label>
</div>
<button type="button" class="uncheck btn">Clear All</button>
<br><br>
<section>
  <div class="box" data-category="a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="c b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="d"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="e"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="f a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="a"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="b"></div>
  <div class="box" data-category="c d"></div>
</section>
```